# POST FormData to php using javascript and XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest, form-data

At the moment I have two files, index.htm and accessdata.php.
This is what I have in index.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function postData() {
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "accessdata.php";
  var checkBoxes_formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("checkBoxes"));

  xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send(checkBoxes_formData);

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="postData()">POST</button>

<form id=checkBoxes>
<table>
    <tr><input type="checkbox" name="opt1" value="blue" checked> Blue</td>
    <tr><input type="checkbox" name="opt2" value="yellow"> Yellow</td> 
</table>
</form>

<p id="result"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is what I have in accessdata.php:

```
<?php

$opt1=$_POST['opt1'];
echo $opt1;

echo "bla";
?>
```

Now, on

```
<p id="result"></p>
```

"bla" shows up, but not "blue", or "yellow".

What am I doing wrong?

THE CORRECT HTML CODE BELOW!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>POST PHP XMLHTTPRequest</title>
<script>
function postData() {
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "accessdata.php";
  var checkBoxes_formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("checkBoxes"));

  xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(checkBoxes_formData);

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="postData()">POST</button>

<form id="checkBoxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="opt1" value="blue"> Blue
<input type="checkbox" name="opt2" value="yellow" checked> Yellow

</form>

<p id="result"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: close form with </form>

Comment: ok, already did that, my mistake when building he example code, still it doesn't work.

Comment: I never used FormData, but it seems you shouldn't set a content type. Anyway, check what form the returned FormData is. I would start echoing the whole $_POST data. But before you can `console.log(checkboxes_formData)` this often helps understanding what happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`blue` doesn't show up because you are claiming:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

But `FormData` objects encode data as `multipart/form-data`.

Remove the code that explicitly sets the content-type and let the browser generate it for you. (Don't try to explicitly set it to `multipart/form-data`, you have to specify what the boundary marker is going to be in the header too).

`yellow` doesn't show up for the same reason, but also because:

- You are only looking at `opt1` and it is associated with the name `opt2` *and*
- Checkbox controls are only successful (i.e. will be in the data that gets submitted) if they are checked (which the yellow one is not by default).

Complicating matters further, your HTML is invalid. [Use a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/). You can't have an input as a child of a table row, you need to create a table data cell between them. (Note that it looks like you are trying to use a table for layout, you should probably get rid of the table entirely).

Comment: I didn't know there were validators available! Wow this is great! I will revise the code and edit the post so that the validator gives as few errors as I can make it.

Comment: The table is used to put many checkboxes in place, 30 or so, in different columns. I didn't know that it wouldn't work if the inputs were inside the same table row. Removed the table and the line xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); and then it worked.

Comment: "Remove the code that explicitly sets the content-type and let the browser generate it for you." This made the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Been going round in circles for ages till I saw this comment on the setHeaderRequest type.

Answer (score 0):

Tap to create a note
You should try this…

```
<form method=post action=accessdata.php>
    <input type=checkbox value=blue name=opt1>blue
    <input type=submit value=submit name=send>
</form>
```

In accessdata. PHP

```
if❨isset❨$_POST[`send']❩❩ {
    $color=$_POST[`opt1'];
    echo $color."bala";
}
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error in that, so it won't work … and it doesn't do what the code in the question is trying to do anyway.