# How do I send html form parameters using ajax POSt and javascript? I think I misused FormData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In order to display a calendar, I need to send some form parameters from page `Calendar_form2.php` to `Calendar_form3.php` and then I want to display the results from `Calendar_form3.php` in `Calendar_form2`.

From what I understand Ajax POST is the correct way to do it because I need to send user form parameters and its more secure.

The problem is that the page `Calendar_form3.php` do not recognised the `$_POST['string']` post variables I send to him.

I'm using FormData in order to send the form parameters.

Here is the code in page `Calendar_form2.php`:

```
<body>

    <form id="my-form-id" method="post" action="Calendar_form3.php">

        Year:<INPUT NAME="gregorian_year" SIZE=4 MAXLENGTH=4 value="2016">(1-6000)
        Latitude: <INPUT NAME="latitude" value="40.7127">
        Longitude: <INPUT NAME="longitude" value="-74.0059">
        <button id="ajax-button" type="button">Ajax button</button>

    </form>

    <script>
        function displayCalendar() {
            var divtarget = document.getElementById("main");
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("my-form-id"));
            console.log(formData);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('post', 'Calendar_form3.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                console.log('readyState: ' + xhr.readyState);
                if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                    divtarget.innerHTML = 'LOADING';
                }
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var text = xhr.responseText;

                    divtarget.innerHTML = text;
                }
            }
            xhr.send(formData);
        }

        var button = document.getElementById("ajax-button");
        button.addEventListener("click", displayCalendar);
    </script>

    <div id='main'>
        result here
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the code in page `Calendar_form3.php`:

```
<?php
echo "ajax working!!";
echo $_POST['gregorian_year'] . $_POST['latitude']. $_POST['longitude'];
?>
```

When I run this code the "ajax working!!" is displaying but then I get 3 errors:

"Notice: Undefined index: gregorian_year"
   "Notice: Undefined index: latitude"
   "Notice: Undefined index: longitude in"

I think the problem may be in FormData somewhere.
Anyone knows what is the problem?

Another question i got: lets say I want to send the parameters without using FormData. How can I send it? what do I target the value inserted by the user? Something like this?

```
xhr.send(gregorian_year=UserValueOfgregorian_year&latitude=UserValueOflatitude&longitude=UserValueOflongitude);
```

Would appreciate any help! Thank!

Comment: the content-type is wrong! look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102473/post-formdata-to-php-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest

Comment: simply remove the line `setRequestHeader(....)`!

Comment: As for your last question, yes you would use that type of string

Comment: thanks! dropping the setRequestHeader(....) solved it.
regarding my second question: how can i target the user value of the form fields? i only know how to target thier name... 
xhr.send(gregorian_year=?&latitude=?&longitude=?);